# Bootstrap Codeigniter 3 Form Click on edit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

```
<legend data-target="#basic_information" data-toggle="collapse">Basic Information</legend>
        <fieldset id="basic_information" class="collapse">
          <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Screen Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="screen_name" placeholder="Screen Name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            </div>
            <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">First Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            </div>
                      <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Middle Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="middle_name" placeholder="Middle Name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            </div>

                      <!-- Text input-->
            <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Last Name</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Birthdate</label>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select name="birthdate-month" id="birthdate-month">
                <option value="">month</option>
                <?php foreach($month as $month_number => $month_name) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $month_number; ?>" <?php echo set_select('birthdate-month', $month_number); ?>><?php echo $month_name; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select name="birthdate-day" id="birthdate-day">
                <option value="">day</option>
                <?php for($i=1; $i<=31; $i++){ ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php echo set_select('birthdate-day', $i); ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2">
              <select name="birthdate-year" id="birthdate-year">
                <option value="">year</option>
                <?php for($i=(date("Y")-10); $i>=1930; $i--) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i; ?>" <?php echo set_select('birthdate-month', $i); ?>><?php echo $i; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Gender</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select name="gender" id="gender">
                    <option value=""></option>
                    <option value="male">Male</option>
                    <option value="female">Female</option>
                </select>   
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Occupation</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="job" placeholder="Occupation" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <!-- Text input-->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Address</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
              <input type="text" name="address" placeholder="Address" class="form-control">
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
              <div class="pull-right">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

        </fieldset>
```

I've added the collapse feature of Bootstrap on the above code. Whenever i click on the BASIC INFORMATION text, it would show the details, as it is hidden by default.

What i want to do is the same as the collapse feature.

I want the above code to be read only, i'm pretty sure i can do that with html.

What i want to do is to make it so that i only have to click on the input and it will be available for me to edit one by one or clicking a button and everything will be editable.

solely using bootstrap, like with what i did with collapse.

Is it possible? or do i need to use jquery.

Comment: You can't make `<select>`s read-only. It sounds like you want a second toggle (first is the title that shows the form section, second is a button that enables editing). Though, I don't understand why; if you can edit an input by clicking on it, what's the point of read-only?

Comment: I mean, whenever the profile is shown, its not directly customizeable. You'd have to click on a button to make everything editable and/or click on the label to make the corresponding value editable.

That's what i meant.

Comment: I didn't want to make 2 html pages, one for showing profile details and one for editing them.

But then again, if this is the better process of the two then let me know so i'll go for it and not hesitate anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using bootstrap and with jquery code like this :-

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#basic_information').on('hidden.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#basic_information .form-control').attr('readonly', true);/*It will add the readonly attribute in all input on collapse*/
        });
        $('#basic_information').on('shown.bs.collapse', function () {
            $('#basic_information .form-control').attr('readonly', false);/*It will remove as soon as your basic information get expanded*/
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Is there not a way to do this without using jquery?

I want to maximize my use of bootstrap. Just like with what i did with collapse. Couldve used jquery but bootstrap already provides its own function.

Answer (score -1):

Put a `<span>` adjacent to each form control with a common class like `currentvalue`, each one holding the text of the current value for that field. Add a single button at the top that uses JS/jQuery to toggle visibility between those spans, and the inputs (including the submit button). Then you have one file but its functionality is switchable. If you're using ajax to submit the form, then you'll also have to update the `<span>`s' contents on successful submit.